# Proving center of a tree consists of one vertex or two adjacent vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to use a technique where you take each vertex $v$ of $T$ and consider the path to the farthest vertex from it $v'$.  Orient the first edge of the path toward $v'$.  Assuming $T$ has $n$ vertices, then there are $n-1$ edges.  By Pigeonhole Principle one edge was oriented twice.

From here I am trying to show that one or both of 2 vertices connected to this edge that was oriented twice has minimal eccentricity.  I was thinking a contradiction argument would make sense where we assume some other vertex has minimal eccentricity and show that the path to the farthest element from that vertex must go through one of the 2 vertices connected to the edge that was oriented twice.  I can't seem to come up with a solid argument for this.

Comment: My answer to the earlier question suggests a simpler approach.

Comment: I am trying to use this technique of directing edges but my issue is in finishing the argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can also use some sort of induction argument. Each longest path always ends in a leaf of a tree. Furthermore, every tree of at least 3 vertices has at least two leaves, and deleting those leaves does not change the centers of the tree (since a leaf cannot be a center). Then you can use induction.